# Conditional Random Variable - Notation Question

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a compound binomial random variable (i.e. having a compound binomial distribution):

$$X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,P)\tag1$$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is fixed and the success probability $P$ is some random variable. As I understand, (1) is equivalent to

$$X|(P=p)\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)\tag2$$

**Question:** does it make sense to write

$$X|P\sim\text{Binomial}(n,P)\tag3$$

- Given (1) I am hesitant to write (3), but since (2) is equivalent to (1) it feels like (3) is just a shorter notation for (2). Please, let me know if I am wrong here!
- Some people use this "standalone" notation like $X|P$, some only use it under conditional expectation and I feel like they are deliberately trying to avoid introducing it, so I wonder how one should do/write it correctly...

Comment: Contrary to heropup's answer, I don't think (1) is imprecise at all. Often times, this is exactly how dependent random variables are generated, e.g. by means of a markov kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually not write $(1)$, for the reason that capitalization of letters to denote random variables is not a universally followed practice and it is not necessarily a reliable visual indicator that $X$ obeys a hierarchical model.  Another reason for not using $(1)$ is that it becomes unclear how you would specify the *unconditional* or marginal distribution of $X$.  For instance, if $P$ obeys a beta distribution, then the marginal distribution is called [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).  Specifically, I would write such a hierarchical model as follows:

$$P \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta), \\ X \mid P \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, P), \\ X \sim \operatorname{BetaBinomial}(n, \alpha, \beta).$$

Note how we have clearly distinguished the conditional distribution of $X$ given $P$, which is binomial, versus the unconditional/marginal distribution of $X$, which is beta-binomial (and no longer depends on $P$).

For these two major reasons, I would say at best $(1)$ is imprecise, and at worst, incorrect.

$(2)$ and $(3)$ are conceptually equivalent, much in the way that we regard something like $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]$$ as a function of the random variable $Y$, and $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y = y]$$ as a function of the realization $y$.

Comment: I generally agree with what you write and I personally favor (3) vs (1). What still makes me a bit uncertain about (3) is that explicitly denoting the dependence of $X$ on $P$ as a conditioning is not something you do when you write "strict" equations between random variables, like $X=\sum_{i=1}^NB_i(p)$ with $B_i(p)$ being iid Bernoulli and $N$ Poisson. Here, on the LHS, you don't write $X|N$ though $X$ clearly depends on $N$, but if I undertand you correctly you would still write $X|N\sim\text{Binomial}(N,p)$, right?

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos There is a difference between saying, for instance, $$X = Y + Z$$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables, and saying $$X \sim \operatorname{SomeDistribution}(Y,Z).$$  The latter is sloppy and problematic for the reasons I have already stated.  You are conflating functions of random variables with the distributions of random variables.  One uses an equals sign; the other uses a tilde/$\sim$ sign.

Comment: For your other example, if $N$ were a random variable and $p$ fixed, then the notation $$X \mid N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N,p)$$ is correct.  If one wrote $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N,p),$$ then I ask again:  what notation would you use to specify the unconditional distribution of $X$?  You cannot then subsequently write $X \sim \operatorname{SomethingElse}$.  The fact of the matter is that it is **only** the conditional distribution of $X$ that is binomial.  Once you marginalize and remove the condition, $X$ is no longer necessarily binomial, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, all clear now. "You are conflating functions of random variables with the distributions of random variables. One uses an equals sign; the other uses a tilde (\sim)
 sign." Indeed I was doing that, at least in my mind, and that generated the uncertainty around these notations.